# Jenkins sparse checkout: only content of directory

Tags: git, jenkins, sparse-checkout

I have a repo: hello.git. I'm able to perform a sparse checkout:
`sparse checkout path`: /test/test1

Now I have this in my workspace:

```
.../workspace/test/test1/content
```

I want to have the following:

```
.../workspace/content
```

Is it possible to checkout only the content of the path you describe?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not possible in git.

When you checkout in sparse mode, git only updates entries matched by your configuration in $GIT_DIR/info/sparse-checkout (this is set by the Git plugin on Jenkins).

Git does not support changing the root of the working tree in checkout. So when you do a sparse checkout, you will always have the whole directory structure of the files you selected.

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout

Comment: While I don't think it's possible in Jenkins, but to complete your answer:
Technically it is possible to change the root of a working tree directly from git with `git filter-branch --subdirectory-filter <subdirectory>`.
Note: It happens after the checkout, and it is only possible when making read-only checkouts as the repo is no longer compatible with upstream.

Comment: Although I still don't think it's possible, it's worth mentioning the way Git can do this from version 2.19 on: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52269934/344480